# Django- getting the value of 'models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.today)' in view

Tags: python, django, datetime, view, model

I have this model:

**models.py:**

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(P,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

    **date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.today)**
```

In the views.py, I get the data of "date" field:

**views.py**

```
from appX.models import myModel
from datetime import datetime

...
def my_items(request):
   ...
   got_date = myModel.objects.get(id = 1).date
   got_date_2 = datetime.strptime(got_date, "%YYYY-%MM-%d")
```

But python throws the following error:

```
time data '"2024-02-14"' does not match format '%YYYY-%MM-%d'
```

What "format" should I use ?

The date is fetched from the database, then stored in a session, then extracted again as an "str" called "got_date"; thus I want to convert it to date object -the same used in django's date field- again to pass to a different database table using "strptime".

Comment: The purpose of `strptime()` is to parse a date string in a certain format and return an actual date object.  But your model `date` field is already an actual date object.  So why are you using `strptime()` at all?

Comment: Also, `%MM` is not a valid date token.  `%m` is month, and `%M` is minutes.  So `%MM` is interpreted as minutes followed by the actual letter M.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work with date formatting as is done in Django templates (which was borrowed from PHP), but as defined by Python's [`datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), so:

```
got_date_2 = datetime.strptime(got_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I fixed the error by converting "got_date" to "str" using:

```
got_data = str(myModel.objects.get(id = 1).date)
got_date_2 = datetime.strptime(got_date, "%Y-%m-%d")**
```

Then the error was resolved.

Thanks for pointing out the mistake in the format too.